# Azure Search service highlighted snippet

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is available feature highlighted snippet on Azure Search service? if yes then how it is possible to retrieve result highlighted snippet on Azure search service.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit this site and check how to ask a good question, in order to increase your chances to get an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Search supports hit highlighting, with the ability retrieve a snippet with the highlighted text. You can learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents).  Just search for the word "highlight".  You can also customize how the text is highlighted.  For example, you can tell it to use bold or underlines.